# Cakephp unique view count

Tags: cakephp, count, cakephp-2.0, unique

I'm trying to make my view count only counting unique visitors.

In my Item Controller of Cakephp 2.x I have the following:

```
function view($slug = null) {
    [...]
    $this->Item->updateAll(
        array('Item.hits'=>'Item.hits+1'),
        array('Item.slug'=>$slug)
    );
}
```

This adds +1 to the hit column and works fine.
The flaw is, that clicking the view many times increases the count.

Any idea how I could make a unique count?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

quick solution

```
[...]
if($this->Session->check('has_read_item.' . $slug) === false) {
    $this->Item->updateAll(array('Item.hits'=>'Item.hits+1'),array('Item.slug'=>$slug));
    $this->Session->write('has_read_item.' . $slug, true);
}
[...]
```

This sets a unique session for each item viewed, based on the slug.

If the session does not already exist, the user hasn't viewed the article, so increase the hit and then set the session.

If the session does already exist; don't update it again.

---

This means that one user can't increase the hits per item, more than once in any one session, which is about as good as you'll get in a few lines of code.

Anything more accurate will take a lot of effort and it's likely just not worth it.

Comment: It is working when I strip the "== false" of the first line.
Thanks a lot. Could you please update your answer

Comment: `Session::check()` returns `false` when the session does not exist, so  it should be there. If the session does not exist, we want to update the `hit` and then set the session, preventing it from firing again.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP Counter Helper: CakePHP helper to display visitor statistics

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7391-PHP-CakePHP-helper-to-display-visitor-statistics.html

This is manual installation for CakePHP Counter Helper

When you downloaded package, extract it to anywhere.

1. First, go to your PHP MyAdmin -> Your database import "init.sql" file to create Table for helper.
2. Copy "model\counter.php" into your model directory.
3. Copy folder "counter" to "webroot/img/" => this is image files.
4. Copy main file "counter.php" into "app/view/helpers/" directory.

All done.

Usage please read example.php